# Is spacetime really just time, with no aspect of space?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time

In my questions on gravity, I've come to the understanding that spacetime is really just time, and there is no need for space. Anything that requires a distance (for example the distance between two massive bodies for gravitation calculations) could just be a function of time.  Can anyone show that there is a need for dimensions of space in spacetime?

To further explain what I'm asking.  Michelson Morley proved that there is no aether?  However, it is also correct that the Gravity B Probe mission [Link](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/42908643/ns/technology_and_science-space/t/satellite-confirms-we-live-space-time-warp/#.W84NevlRdnA) proved that there is a bending of spacetime out there.  So, if you subtract one from the other, it seems to show there is no space in spacetime.

It seems to me that the only thing required for gravity to work is the time dilation caused by a massive body.  We talk about the bending of spacetime, as if it is a 4 dimensional thing.  We talk about gravitational waves as ripples in spacetime, but are they really only waves in time?  We can see time dilation at work. But can we see spacetime dilation?  Can you show me how the dimensions of space are required for gravity?

Here is another way of putting it.  There are objects floating around in the universe. The only thing connecting these objects to each other is time, rather than something called spacetime.

I hope that this clarifies the question.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Maybe somebody could help you if you could explain _how_ you came to realize that spacetime really is just time. As it stands, it sounds as if, when you say "spacetime," you are talking about something completely different from what a physicist means when the physicist says "spacetime."

Comment: By using the speed of light, we often do express the distance to an object in units of time (eg: light years).  However, all objects are not along a single line. Some objects are in the x direction, some in y, and some in z, or away in a general vector direction (x,y,z). So your notion of "just time" requires time to be a vector $ (t_x , t_y, t_z,) $.  Actually it needs a fourth component $t_t$ which is the usual time that passes when we watch the hands of a clock go around.  This looks like regular spacetime relabled using light year distances?

Comment: @GaryGodfrey  I'm not saying that there are not different objects out at different locations in the 3 dimensional universe. But rather I'm saying that if there is anything connecting these objects, then it is only time, and not some aspect of space.  And please, keep in mind that I'm looking for a statement that this is not correct.

Comment: Theories aren't so much correct or incorrect as they are useful or not useful. If you want people to take notice of a new theory, then you have to be able to show either, (a) that it predicts new phenomena that no other theory previously has predicted, or (b) that it is easier to use and understand than other theories. Emphasis there is on the word _you_. As in, _you_ have to show (a) or (b). After you've done that, _then_ you'll find it much easier to find people who want to jump in and help you search for a fatal flaw.

Comment: @SolomonSlow   I'm not proposing a new theory. I'm asking a question.  Is our concept of spacetime really just time?  Can anyone show me why the space aspect of it is important, or if it even exists?

Comment: @foolishmuse, in my opinion, you're totally missing the point.  If I want to uniquely locate an object in space, there are several things that I need to do.  1) Establish a coordinate system (assume Cartesian coordinates for the sake of the argument);  2) specify three coordinates, such as x, y, and z;  3)  specify WHEN that object will be at that point.  This means that my model is 4 dimensional, and requires 3 space coordinates and one time coordinate.  For lack of a better term, such a 4 dimensional model was given the name "space-time".

Comment: @DavidWhite  Actually this is a different issue.  Yes, I understand that there are 4 dimensions in locating an object. You could call that 3 dimensions in space, but I'll just use 3 directions in the universe. My question goes to what is spacetime?  Is time the only thing that connects two objects in the universe?  Gravity seems to say that this is correct. Or is there something in space that also connects two objects?

Comment: @foolishmuse, then from a certain perspective, you should realize that "space-time" is a mathematical construct that is used to mathematically describe observations.

Comment: @DavidWhite  That is a good answer to part of my question: Spacetime is a mathematical construct.   I'll fully accept that.  But Time is not a mathematical construct, it is a real thing.  So are "ripples in spacetime" really "ripples in time"?

Comment: @foolishmuse, special relativity has already proven that space and time are connected (see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/tdil.html).  If you maintain that time is "real", and you maintain that special relativity is "real", then you should also maintain that space-time is "real".

Comment: @foolishmuse If I'm following you right, in your arguments, you seem to be focusing on celestial objects separated by varying gravitational fields and you thus call the *distance* between them as *time*. Well, if that's so, then how would the same argument explain the distance that separates any two bodies in a local reference frame -- i.e. uniform gravitational field?

Comment: The idea has been put forth elsewhere that what we call spacetime is actually a 4D global time continuum.  This is an interesting thought that I am pursuing.  Thanks all.

Comment: "what we call spacetime is actually a 4D global time continuum" That does not work as I explained in my answer below.  4D global time continuum would be a signature of (----), which is incompatible with observation.

Comment: @Dale  thanks for pointing that out. Now that I am on a particular line of thinking your answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly there is a need for dimensions of space in spacetime. The signature of spacetime is (-+++). You cannot get that signature with only time which would be (-) or (----) depending on how many dimensions of time you were considering.

The (-) signature would not work since it would forbid any closed curves and we know that there are closed spacelike curves. The (----) signature would also not work since it would allow closed timelike curves in flat spacetime. So we need space to fit with the observed geometry of the universe. Time alone is not sufficient.

Comment: Can you give me an example of where we need space to fit the observed topology of the universe?    For example, can the bending of light around a star be explained only by the bending of time, or is bending of space also necessary?   Can this be proven mathematically?

Comment: Nothing so exotic is needed. If you walk around your table you wind up back where you started but not back when you started. You can draw loops that are closed in space but not in time. That fact indicates that there is only one dimension of time, but multiple dimensions of space.

Answer (score 2):

There are phenomena occurring on same axis (dot product) and orthogonal axis (cross product). If time was the only dimension, then how would orthogonality be possible? You would need at least two dimensions, so at least one dimension of space is necessary.

Comment: I'm not saying that there are not objects at different places in the universe. What I'm asking is, is there anything in between them "space" or is there just "time" in between them?  Is gravity really just the bending of time, and not "spacetime"? There is no "space" at all

Comment: @foolishmuse, What is your reason for saying that the space that separates two different events is _nothing_, but the time that separates them is _something?_

Comment: @foolishmuse I somewhat understand what you are getting at (for example using light speed as unit of distance), but your question was about "dimensions of space". It would be great if you rephrase your question and re ask.

Comment: @SolomonSlow  I've edited the original question.  We know that there are gravitational waves, but perhaps these are simply waves in time, rather than spacetime.  We can see time dilation at work.  Can we see any effect from the space portion?

Comment: @foolishmuse "Can we see any effect from the space portion?"  Sure, look up LIGO. The distance between freely suspended mirrors changes when a gravitational wave is passing by, which is measured by laser techniques.